# What is the best image size of floating action button

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I included a FAB in my app but when I try to set src image then it's getting smaller than expected. What is the optimal image size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button) 24 x 24dp:

[image: Floating Action Button icon size]

Answer (score 3):

*tl;dr*: Optimal size is **32x32** if you are using a `FloatingActionButton` control - this is what Android Studio uses.

---

[Marcin is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191895/383414) when he points at the UI spec:

> According to Material Design Guidelines 24 x 24dp

This defines how big the icon should appear on screen, once the framework renders it in the FAB control.

---

*But* that is not the same as **what size icon to use in your app**, since the framework does some scaling for you.

Android Studio sample code for a Basic Activity creates a layout with a FAB in it defined like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

Looking at that `ic_dialog_email` in my installed SDK25 gives me the following 32x32 image at `mdpi` density:

[image: ic_dialog_email.png]

---

So **32x32 is the optimal image size** to use in your app. The framework will scale it appropriately to display at 24x24.

Answer (score 0):

use this xml code in floating actiob button xml define :

```
app:fabSize="normal|mini"
```

Answer (score 0):

this type of problems happens when one do not apply proper padding according to material design guide lines or have only one image/icon for use . try to put icons in specific folder ie(hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi ...) .Then android system automatically pic icon as per device Density Pixel.
 if you have done all in proper way try to us `app:fabsize="";` property